# How to remove append value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

This is my code. It's working for first item append.

When click show count button I show in pop up dialog box. But removal of that append or reload page is required

```
function showcount()
{
 $('#dropitemcount').append(count);
}
```

Output is : `2`

When i click again that show button

output is : `2 2`

third time : `2 2 2`

How to resolve this item?

It's possible to elemetn.remove().append()

Answer (score 2):

Try this if it is helpful to you.

```
var count="<span>"+count+"</span>";
function showcount(){
    $('#dropitemcount').find('span').remove(); 
    $('#dropitemcount').append(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var dropitemcount = $('#dropitemcount');//cache selector
function showcount() {
    dropitemcount.find('span').remove(); //remove span 
    dropitemcount.append('<span>' + count + '</span>'); //add new span with new count
}
```

---

Or

Change your html add `span` tag inside it

```
var dropitemcount = $('#dropitemcount'); //cache selector
function showcount() {
    dropitemcount.find('span').text(count);  //set text of count to span
}
```

---

If you just have to show count in div nothing else use

```
$('#dropitemcount').text(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question but it looks like append is doing exactly what you're telling it to do. If your trying to change the content than try this:

```
 $('#dropitemcount').html(count);
```

Also, make sure you increment your count as well.